# .NET MVC 3 Rollback in Dbcontext

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, transactions, dbcontext

in MVC 3 is it possible to rollback the database after calling DbContext.SaveChanges() ?

My entities class:

```
public class BipEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Page> Pages { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ImageFile> ImageFiles { get; set; }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is insert a ImageFile record into the db, then by using the auto-incremented id as the image filename, save the image file into somewhere else. 
When System.IO fails, I would like to rollback the database.

```
BipEntities db = new BipEntities();
db.Database.Connection.Open();
DbTransaction tranx = db.Database.Connection.BeginTransaction();

ImageFile img = new ImageFile { CreatedAt = DateTime.Now };
db.ImageFiles.Add(img);
db.SaveChanges();

string filename = "img" + img.Id.ToString() + ".png";
try {
    //Works on system IO to process file
    tranx.Commit();

} Catch ( Exception) {
    tranx.Rollback();
}

db.Database.Connection.Close();
```

However, the above code gives me this error message:

```
EntityConnection can only be constructed with a closed DbConnection.
```

Comment: why don't you use guid as a filename and add that as separate column in db, than you first save a file and than insert row in db. no need for transaction just try/catch.

Comment: @frennky, thanks for the suggestion, but I would like to find out the answer anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap your `DbContext` in a database transaction, either using a `TransactionScope` or creating the `DbContext` using a `DbConnection` that runs inside a transaction:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
{
    con.Open();
    using (var tran = con.BeginTransaction())
    {
        var img = new Image();

        using (var db = new BipEntities(con))
        {
            db.Images.AddObject(img);

            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        // Write to disk here.
        WriteStuffToDisk(stuff, img.Id);

        tran.Commit();
    }        
}
```

Comment: I guess this is what I wanted, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `.saveChanges()` **is** your commit. If you want to rollback, just don't do a `.saveChanges` and just close your Database Access Layer, no changes will be saved.

```
using(var db = new dbconnection())
{
    myEntity item = new myEntity { Name = "Hello" };

    db.tblofmyEntities.AddObject(item);

    if (item.Name != "FOO")
         db.SaveChanges();

}
```

The item will be saved because its name is not "FOO". if it is "FOO", it will not be saved. When the application reaches the `}` therefore no item will be saved. You can call the `.AddObject()` function before or inside the if-block, doesn't make much difference.

Comment: I need .SaveChanges() to get the auto-incremented id.

Comment: That is the "largest ID", it is different from "Last auto incremented ID"

Comment: You could use the function " select last_insert_id() " in a query to get the last created id, but you need to make sure you're doing it in the same database context.